# Rsync creating infinite nested directories

Tags: rsync, symlink

To be truthful, I don't really know if this is caused by symlinks or rsync but I've stopped using symlinks and migrated over to using rsync months ago. So I guess this is just to be sure %100.

This is my command: `rsync -azsL $src $dst` and how I use it as a function in php;

```
protected function cloneDirectory($src, $dst) {
    if (!is_dir($dst)) {
      mkdir($dst, 0777, true);
    }

    $command = "rsync -azsL $src $dst";
    exec($command, $output, $return_val);
  }
```

I'm not sure if the source string has a trailing slash or not but if the solution is to add a trailing slash, can be done easily.

Structure of source directory:

`{content_id}/system`: consists of files and directories and I bundle one or more of these into the destination. Example;

```
x (folder_x/system/...)
y (folder_y/system/...)
```

So the goal is to merge the contents of both `x/system` and `y/system` in destination and  I end up having an infinite `system/system/` for ever.

Is this potentially caused by `rsync`? If so, how can I stop this from happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow the example below.

If I have src=/a/b/test path having the file test and another is dst=/c/d. If I need to rsync that file from src to destination.

I will use this command.

```
rsync -azsL /a/b/ /c/d
```

So, the solution for your problem is:

```
src=x/system/ dst=y/system
```